# meteor stopped working after update to version 0.5.5

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've upgraded *meteor* to version *0.5.5* today. after restarting the server, my site stopped working, because bootstrap modals don't appear. The meteor change logs shows an update to *bootstrap 2.3.0* and *jquery 1.9* included.

Are there any known problems with this versions? especially with modals?

Btw: The browser shows the following error in jquery.js on loading:

```
Unhandled Error: Maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: I just updated to 0.5.5 and use modals on my site. Things are fine. So no errors with the version. Are you selecting DOM in loops?

Comment: No, i'm not selecting DOM in loops...

Comment: Can you gist the complete exception stack?

Comment: Thank you very much! You point me to the right direction. My idle detection was the problem. I use the jquery plugin from [here](https://github.com/mikesherov/jquery-idletimer). In the previous bootstrap and jquery versions the timer stoped working, everytime a modal appears. So i disabled him in the 'show' events of the modal and enabled him again in the 'hide' event. I haven't tested it with the current versions, yet. But this was the problem. Again: thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment copied into question so it can be accepted:

> Thank you very much! You point me to the right direction. My idle detection was the problem. I use the jquery plugin from here. In the previous bootstrap and jquery versions the timer stoped working, everytime a modal appears. So i disabled him in the 'show' events of the modal and enabled him again in the 'hide' event. I haven't tested it with the current versions, yet. But this was the problem. Again: thank you! :)